# Sum of residues.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $q$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with distinct zeroes $z_1,\ldots,z_n$. Let $p$ be a polynomial of degree $n-2$ or less. Show that:

$\displaystyle\sum_{K=1}^{n} \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{p}{q};z_k\right)=0$

I'm trying to think of ways to use the residue theorem, but I'm not sure how to proceed...any input would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** integrate over a really large circle.

Comment: I was going to ask a similar question. I still don't understand how to proceed. How do we proceed?

Comment: @User69127 Use the "ML-inequality" to show that $$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{|z|=R} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\, dz = 0.$$